# Acumatica - error when trying to copy vendor attribute

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a problem when i tried to automate the vendor field in my customization screen which attribute came from bills and adjustments(vendor field). It throw an error saying that "Vendor cannot be found in the system. Please verify whether you have proper access rights to this object.". But this problem occurs only when i automate it from other screen like invoice(SO30300).

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting image with your code add the code to the question

Comment: Such attributes like `VendorActive` needs some DataViews for proper work. Check the DataVies which the attribute is using.

Comment: Thank you Samvel!